# Connect the walls algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I have to figure out an algorithm, which finds a solution for the Connect the Walls game.

In Connect the Wall we've got rectangle shape board divided into equal, square cells. In each cell we can put a diagonal wall  (directed from left upper corner to right bottom or from left bottom corner to right upper). We have to put walls in all the empty spaces according to the following rules:

> 1. Each cell must contain a wall
> 2. The walls must not form closed loop (we can't "brick up")
> 3. The number of walls connecting to a pillar must match the number written
>      on the pillar
> 4. Additionally some cells might contain a wall which we can't move.

[Connect the walls online game](http://www.onlinegames.net/games/1983/connect-the-walls.html)

Please help.

EDIT:

Ok. I've managed to write simplifying algorithm in C. I need someone to check me. It works for now like this: [Steps](http://marooou.edomena.pl/steps.jpg)

Moreover, I have a question about the last brute-force step.
Can I pick a random cell for start? (maybe there is faster way)
The brute-force algorithm as I understand it:

> 1. Choose the first cell and mark it / or \
> 2. Check if it meets pillars criteria and if there are no cycles
> 3. If everything's ok go to the empty neighbour cell, if not back up and
>      change wall direction in previous cell
>      (if we didn't do it before)
> 4. Loop until we won't have empty cells on our board. Is that right?

And one more issue concerning fast cycle check.
I've figured out that I could use disjoint sets and connected components of graph features.
So...We keep connected components of graph in find-union structure.
If a new recently added edge (wall) connects points from the same connected component - it's a cycle.

Comment: Kinda homework. As Stephen Chung wrote I've tried to get rid of border cases first for pillars "0" "2" and corner "1". Then all the "4" pillars. Then exclude all the cases when we have "x" pillars and x free spots around (occupied spots are not connected to current pillar). Then...i don't know

Comment: I tried "human computer" method (i.e. playing the game) and it looks like simply iterating through these steps will get to the answer.  Very seldom needing more than one level of search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fun game.  Sort of like mine-sweeper.

Are you interested in only a way to get the solution?  In that case, it is a simple tree-search.  Sort of like solving a maze.  Backtracking and stuff.  Easy to prune subtrees since the restrictions are quite tight.

A quick way? Look for all "2" pillars on the border.  Fill them all first.  Also fill the "1" pillars at corners.  Mark all walls connecting to "0" pillars as impossible, but mark all the other directions (because all those squares must be marked).

Then for each pillar that has the requisit numbers of walls, mark all other connecting walls to that pillar as impossible, mark all other directions.  Then mark all the other walls connected to "3" pillars with one impossible wall.  The mark all the other walls connected to "2" pillars with two impossible walls.  Then "1" pillars.  Loop.

After simplifying your board like this, you'll have to do a normal tree search on the remaining unspecified walls.  Mark one potential wall, then loop through the above again to eliminate possibilities.

Comment: So in the end it's sort of N Bishops Problem? I'll try to implement it and see how that works. Thanks for hints.

Comment: Well, the N-bishops problem requires you to go through a search tree.  This one looks like you can just do it with iteration alone.  May not even need to go down one level on the tree.  Every move you make eliminates a whole range of possibilities and also mandates other moves etc.

Comment: And what about "4" pillars? You forgot to mention it and I think we can also exclude cells around them.

Comment: @marooou, yes.  That also.  Left it as an exercise.  :-)

Comment: @marooou, something I didn't mention.  You will have to detect loops though.  That may require recursion.  When I played the game, some positions have multiple possibilities, ruled out only by the requirement of avoiding loops.